# For each postive integer $n:$ $a_n=\frac{n^2}{n^2-45n+675}.$ Evaluate $a_1+2a_2+3a_3+\cdots+44a_{44}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

For each postive integer $n:$
$a_n=\frac{n^2}{n^2-45n+675}.$
Evaluate $a_1+2a_2+3a_3+\cdots+44a_{44}$

What I have tried:
I have taken $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_{44}$ and put these values into $a_1+2a_2+3a_3+\cdots+44a_{44}.$

Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Any guidance will be highly appreciated.Thank you!

Comment: Try pairing $ka_k+(n-k)a_{n-k}$

Comment: @HariShankar I think you mean $ka_k + (45-k)a_{45-k}$. ($n$ has a different meaning in the problem, so I'm avoiding letting notation do double duty)

Comment: I tried what Calvin suggests and got great results!

Comment: @CalvinLin oh i was distracted while typing it. But yes, thats what I intended

Comment: **Hint** $ $ *pair-up* summands as below. OP is case $\,na_n = 135 b_n,\, c_n = n^3,\,k=45$ $$\large b_n = \dfrac{c_n}{c_n+c_{k-n}}\,\Rightarrow\, b_n+b_{k-n}=1\qquad$$

Answer (score 1):

$a_{45-n}=\frac{(45-n)^2}{(45-n)^2-45(45-n)+675}= \frac{(45-n)^2}{n^2-45n+675}$

The denominator is the same! So $na_n+(45-n)a_{45-n}=\frac{n^3}{n^2-45n+675}+
\frac{(45-n)^3}{n^2-45n+675}$. Now we use the fact that $x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)$:$$
\begin{align}
na_n+(45-n)a_{45-n}&=\frac{(n+(45-n))(n^2-n(45-n)+(45-n)^2)}{n^2-45n+675}\\
&=\frac{45(n^2-45n+n^2+45^2-90n+n^2)}{n^2-45n+675}\\
&=\frac{45(3n^2-135n+45^2)}{n^2-45n+675}\\
&=135
\end{align}
$$
So each pair works out to a constant value, $135$ and there are $22$ pairs total. The sum is $2970$

Answer (score 0):

Based on what Hari Shankar mentioned above:

> Try pairing $ka_k+(n−k)a_{n-k}$.

Here $n = 45$.

Doing that will yield:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{22}\left(\frac{k^3}{k^2-45k+675} + \frac{(45-k)^3}{(45-k)^2 -45(45-k) + 675}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{22}135=2970.$$